# Rails skip default_scope when query with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to skip default_scope while querying in rails console

E.g

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope do
   where("type != 'guest'")
  end
end
```

Query be like with association

E.g

```
p = Product.last
p.users.where("...")
```

I need to skip default_scope for user. I tried `p.users.unscoped`, But it fetching all users(not only associated with product)

Comment: Don't use default_scope in the first place. https://andycroll.com/ruby/dont-use-default-scope/

Comment: @max Yes. I am facing the second issue

Comment: Then just use explicit scopes instead of `default_scope`. The article I linked to explains pretty well that `unscoped` removes any scopes and not just the `default_scope` which is why `default_scope` is considered harmful.

Comment: Like max wrote: Don't use `default_scope`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `default_scope`. It's going to bite you in the rear.

The only way to remove `default_scope` scope is to use `unscoped` which as you now have learned removes all scopes - not just the `default_scope`.

So `p.users.unscoped == User.all.unscoped`.

While you can do:

```
User.unscoped.where(product: p)
```

That does not allow you to eager load / include the association to avoid N+1 queries.

Instead of `default_scope` you should use explicit scopes:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :not_guest, ->{ where.not(type: 'guest') }
end
```

You should also be careful with the column name `type` unless you are using it for Single Table Inheritance (STI). ActiveRecord uses it to determine with class to instanciate from database results it can lead to unexpected bugs. If you want use that column name make sure you set the inheritance column to something else:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :not_type
end
```